# Can I check in for connecting flight in Copenhagen CPH without leaving terminal?

Tags: transit, airports, layovers, check-in, cph

I have upcoming flights with short (1 hour) connection in CPH. They are booked as single trip through Kiwi, but are unrelated flights from airlines’ point of view:

- UIA flight in from Kiev KBP (non–schengen)
- Icelandair flight out to Reykjavik KEF (schengen)

Kiwi tells me online check–in won’t be available for the connecting flight (which might or might not be correct from past experience with them, assuming worst case that it won’t be).

**Are there check–in kiosks or transfer desk inside CPH terminal?**

I won't have luggage so re–checking it is not an issue.

I’ve had the similar route last year through ARN and ended up going all the way out of terminal to check in and re–entering through departures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the map available on the aiport's website](https://cph-prod-cdn.azureedge.net/49397e/globalassets/3.-praktisk/1.-hero/transit-area-map.pdf), there is a transfer centre within the transit area (on the map it is shown slightly to the left of the central tax free shopping area).

Comment: I can confirm it is present in reality too. There can be long waits if they're dealing with delays, though.

Comment: Ok, center is encouraging, thank you. There seems to be passport control icon in top left wing (where non–Schengen flights seem to arrive according to site), I wonder is it the same for arrivals and transfers... I.e. do I have to pass immigration w/o boarding pass then get to transfer center instead of exiting to arrivals...